# Probability lower bound on a double cycle on two vertices in random cuckoo graph

Tags: data-structures, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

I have read Chater 17. Balanced Allocations and
Cuckoo Hashing in Mitzenmacher. Upfal. Probability and Computing: Randomization and Probabilistic Techniques in Algorithms and Data Analysis and got stuck with a problem.

We have $m$ elements and $n$ buckets. Each element is hashed into two random buckets (we assume that two our hash functions are completely random). 
If each bucket corresponds to a vertex and each element corresponds to an
edge. Then we have a random graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.
Loops and multi-edges are **allowed**.

What I don't understand is how to get the lower bound on probability
to have a double cycle on two vertices (without self-loops).
To estimate it, the authors first calculate the expected number of double cycles on two vertices. 
It is ${m}\choose{3}$ $(1 - \frac{1}{n}) (\frac{2}{n^2})^2$.
Here $(1 - \frac{1}{n})$ is probability that the first edge doesn't form a self-loop. And $(\frac{2}{n^2})^2$ is probability that two remaining edges
are between the same two vertices as the first one.
Next the authors write:

> We easily observe that when $m = \Omega(n)$ this expectation is
>   $\Omega(1/n)$. A calculation of the variance readily yields the
>   probability that there
>   is such a triple is also $\Omega(1/n)$, using the second moment method.

As I understood the authors mean that using the second moment method ($P(X = 0) \le \frac{Var[X]}{(E[X])^2}$), we can get that $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) \ge 1 - \frac{Var[X]}{(E[X])^2} \ge 1 - n^2 Var[X] = \Omega(1/n)$.
Here $X$ is a random variable that equals to the number of triples of edges
that form double cycle on two vertices.
So this means that Var[X] should be $\frac{1}{n^2} - \Theta(\frac{1}{n^3})$. I tried to calculate variance using the formula
$Var[\sum_i X] = \sum_i Var[X_i] + \sum_{i \not=j} Cov(X_i, X_j)$ since
$X_i$ and $X_j$ aren't independent.
Here $X_i$ is an indicator random variable that equals one when $i$-th
triple of edges form a double cycle on two vertices.
But I always receive a complicated formula that looks like $c_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + c_2 \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} + c_3 \frac{1}{n^3}$.
Here $c_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}$ appears due to term $\sum_i Var[X_i]$ and since $Var[X_i] = \Theta(1/n^2)$. 
Is there a simpler way to calculate variance and show that $P(X \ge 1) = \Omega(1/n)$ or I have a mistake somewhere?

Thank you!